# Error in below oracle queries with respect to From keyboard

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query below but it throws exception when i execute through sqlplus /nolog

```
SELECT 'EXEC DROP_CONSTRAINTS('TK_TYUOICE_REWOURCE','WQEA_INVOTRY');' FROM DUAL
                                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SELECT 'ALTER TABLE WQEA_INVOTRY ADD CONSTRAINT TK_TYUOICE_REWOURCE CHECK (SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('WER','TYU'));' FROM DUAL
                                                                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes in the strings.  For this, just double up on them:

```
SELECT 'EXEC DROP_CONSTRAINTS(''TK_TYUOICE_REWOURCE'', ''WQEA_INVOTRY'');' 
FROM DUAL
```